# After upgrading Magento version 2.1.0 to 2.2.1 getting below error in cart page

Tags: magento2

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'container', attribute 'before': [facet 'pattern'] The value '' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_\.]*|-'.
Line: 1545

Element 'container', attribute 'before': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'elementPositionType'.
Line: 1545


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'container', attribute 'before': [facet 'pattern'] The value '' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_\.]*|-'.
Line: 1545

Element 'container', attribute 'before': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'elementPositionType'.
Line: 1545

#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/var/www/html/v...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(217): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Index.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle()
#14 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index->execute()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#31 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#32 {main}
```